# Convert string to float time odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

When calculate time with relativdelta I get result hours = 5, minutes = 20 how this result merge in display in widget `<field name="total" widget="float_time"/>` in py file field is Float.

Comment: What do you mean as float? Please give an example.

Comment: @GeorgeDaramouskas float field in .py file....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float time will automatically convert time to float number in python. For example, if your time field on form view shows 5:20, float time will be converted to: 5 + 20/60 -> 5.33 in python